# How to add WS-security to .NET Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, ws-security

I'm implementing dummy web service in .Net. *WS* method receives soap request with following header:

```
<s:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></s:Header>
```

How can I get username token? Is there any solution of implementing *WS*-Security in .net?

Comment: Not like this. WCF adds the proper headings and actually manages authentication based on the `web.config` settings. WS-Security isn't just a header, it's an entire workflow and way of managing payloads. The way WS-Security is used is described in the [Message Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-in-wcf) section of the WCF docs.

Comment: What you posted is NOT WS-Security anyway. The `wsse` namespace was used *before* WS-Security was introduced in 2004. Attaching a username/password along with every message is fundamentally wrong and defeats WS-Security too.

Comment: Finally, Web Services are defined by the *server*. The *server* specifies the protocols used and publishes them in a WSDL file. Clients use that WSDL file to generate the actual code. Instead of trying to get the server to accept various XML messages, create a WCF service with the features you want and generate clients from its WSDL